# Page curl with active content

Tags: ios, ios4, viewflipper, page-curl, flipboard

I've got an magazine app. In it, I implement AFK Page Flipper for page curl. But now I have no  idea how to create active content. I mean for example when I've got image on page I want to tap on it and get bigger in model view. Like in Flipboard app. Any ideas? Thx for reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it... Flipboard has page turning on swipe not on tap. So wehn I want to show image I tap. When I want to turn over page, I sipe...